# List.BinarySearch vs Dictionary.TryGetValue - which is faster

Tags: c#

Which would be faster for say 500 elements.

Or what's the faster data structure/collection for retrieving elements?

```
        List<MyObj> myObjs = new List<MyObj>();
        int i = myObjs.BinarySearch(myObjsToFind);
        MyObj obj = myObjs[i];
```

Or

```
        Dictionary<MyObj, MyObj> myObjss = new Dictionary<MyObj, MyObj>();
        MyObj value;
        myObjss.TryGetValue(myObjsToFind, out value);
```

Answer (score 11):

I assume in your real code you'd actually *populate* myObjs - and sort it.

Have you just tried it? It will depend on several factors:

- Do you need to sort the list for any other reason?
- How fast is MyObj.CompareTo(MyObj)?
- How fast is MyObj.GetHashCode()?
- How fast is MyObj.Equals()?
- How likely are you to get hash collisions?
- Does it actually make a significant difference to you?

It'll take around 8 or 9 comparisons in the binary search case, against a single call to GetHashCode and some number of calls to Equals (depending on hash collisions) in the dictionary case. Then there's the intrinsic calculations (accessing arrays etc) involved in both cases.

Is this really a bottleneck for you though?

I'd expect Dictionary to be a bit faster at 500 elements, but not *very* much faster. As the collection grows, the difference will obviously grow.

Answer (score 4):

Have been doing some real world tests with in memory collection of about 500k items.
Binary Search wins in every way.
Dictionary slows down the more hash collision you have. Binary search technically slows down but no where as fast as the dictionaries algorithm.

The neat thing about the binary search is it will tell you exactly where to insert the item into the list if not found.. so making the sorted list is pretty fast too. (not as fast)

Dictionaries that large also consume a lot of memory compared to a list sorted with binary search.  From my tests the sorted list consumed about 27% of the memory a dictionary id.  (so a diction claimed 3.7 X the memory)

For smallish list dictionary is just fine -- once you get largish it may not be the best choice.

Comment: Sounds wonderful.. would be really nice to see the actual code and tests used to generate this.

Comment: Very good answer for mentioning that dictionaries take a lot more memory

Answer (score 2):

The latter.

A binary search runs at O(log n) while a hashtable will be O(1).

Comment: That doesn't guarantee it'll be faster though. It guarantees it will be faster *when n is large enough* but there could be *massive* constant factors involved. Suppose Dictionary always takes 1 second, whereas list takes 1ms * log(n). List will win for a long time. I'm not saying that happens (cont)

Comment: just that your second statement doesn't prove your first. I don't actually know where the cutoff point is for List/Dictionary, and it will depend on the cost of other factors (comparison vs hashcode etc). I suspect at 500 elements dictionary *will* win. I wouldn't like to say without testing though.

Comment: IIRC, they recommend dictionary for anything larger than 10 items.

Answer (score 1):

Big 'O' notation, as used by some of the commenters, is a great guideline to use.  In practice, though, the only way to be sure which way is faster in a particular situation is to *time your own code* before and after a change (as hinted at by Jon).

Answer (score 0):

BinarySearch requires the list to already be sorted. [edit: Forgot that dictionary is a hashtable. So lookup is O(1)]. The 2 are not really the same either. The first one is really just checking if it exists in the list and where it is. If you want to just check existance in a dictionary use the contain method.